# onclick confirm not being prompted

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following in one of my .jsp files:

```
...
<input style = "margin-left: 100px" type="submit" name = "cancel" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" value="Cancel" />
...
```

The above works perfectly, when I click on the submit, a window pops with the corresponding confirmation message. On the other hand, in another .jsp file I have the following (which is nearly the same as above):

```
...
<input style = "margin-left: 100px" type="submit" name = "confirm" onclick="return confirm('Proceed to results?');" value="Confirm" />
...
```

In this case, the prompt window does not appear at all, and when I press on the submit it loads the next page without asking for a confirmation. What is the difference that makes the second example not work as intended?

Comment: [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/thefto_dev/k9nph139/) It works fine in here...

Comment: Is one in a form and the other is not?

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Although in that demo it does work, I tested in eclipse's browser and on Firefox and it doesn't work for me at least.

Comment: @tymeJV both are in a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you gave your input a `name` of `confirm`. Some browsers like Chrome will put named form elements on the global scope (`window`). And since your element is named `confirm` it overwrites `window.confirm` function to be your element.

Simply name your input something else

```
<input type="submit" name="myconfirm" onclick="return confirm('Proceed to results?');" value="Confirm" />
```